# How to add 2 instances of a dynamic component in parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-components, ng-template

I am trying to add 2 instances of pagination component in one of our main page component so the user can change the pagination from any one instance. In view I'm defining dynamic template like this :

```
        <ng-template #dynamicPagerMaster></ng-template>
```

Below mentioned logic i have used to access the dynamic pagination component from controller.

```
            let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(PaginationComponent);
        let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        let pagerComp: PaginationComponent = <PaginationComponent>componentRef.instance;
```

So far i am able to add one instance without any problem.Any suggestion how can i add 2 instances of the same dynamic component in our main page and how to keep them in sync ?

Answer (score 0):

Use two way data binding with  @Input()